# How to get My object, derived from wxFrame through wxTheApp->GetTopWindow()?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm not so good in OOP rules in C++.
I have this Application **OnInit()** callback:

```
bool Application::OnInit()
{
    MainFrame *mainFrame = new MainFrame();

    mainFrame->Show();
    SetTopWindow(mainFrame);

    return true;
}
```

In MainFrame, derived from wxFrame I have private member and getter for it:

```
wxDialog* MainFrame::GetConfigDialog()
{
    return m_ConfigDialog;
}
```

I want to get ConfigDialog in other class, so I call

```
wxTheApp->GetTopWindow()->GetConfigDialog()
```

But it complain about ***wxWindow has no member named GetConfigDialog()***. Can i get my MainFrame from wxTheApp somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things here. First, you need to use [wxGetApp()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__appinitterm.html#gac387a69e740a149f9888e4992a3a4c6c) function. Unlike `wxTheApp`, it returns the application of the derived type, i.e. `Application` and not `wxApp` in your case (and it also returns it as a reference and not a pointer as it's never supposed to be null). Notice that, as explained in the documentation, you need to use `wxDECLARE_APP()` macro to declare this function in the header containing your application class declaration.

Second, you still can't call your derived class `GetConfigDialog()` method via `wxWindow` pointer. You could use a dynamic cast, but this would be ugly and unsafe. Instead, add a method to retrieve the real main frame to your application class (of course, you'd need to store a pointer to it inside it too then), e.g. `GetMainFrame()`.

If you do both, your code would become

```
wxGetApp().GetMainFrame()->GetConfigDisplay()
```

Comment: Ok, I change to wxDECLARE_APP(Application) after class definition in Application.h, but now i have weird error in file with declaration of another class - expected initializer before 'class'. Without using this macro all compiling without error.

Comment: You forgot the semicolon.

Comment: That's it! But... wxGetApp was not declasred in this scope. How to use global scope with this function? ::wxGetApp() doesnt work =////

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. The macro expands into a declaration in the scope in which the macro itself is used, so unless you put it inside some other scope, this is where `wxGetApp()` will be.